# ¿Como imprimir un rango de fechas que tengan hasta 10 arreglos por renglón con las funciones que tengo?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy haciendo un calendario que muestre un rango de fechas, pero quiero que se vean hasta 10 meses en un solo renglón, ¿podrían decirme como corregir la impresión de los calendarios?

```
<?php
    function generarMes($numero_mes,$aio,$renglon)
    {
        $año=$aio;//variable que identifica a partir de que año empieza el calendario
        $cantidad_dias=0;//donde se almacena la cantidad de dias por mes
        $numero_mes=4;//identifica el mes y van desde 1 hasta 12

        switch($numero_mes)//devuelve la cantidad de dias de cada mes
        {
            case 1:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//enero
                $nombre='enero';
                break;
            case 2:
                $cantidad_dias=28;//febrero
                $nombre='febrero';
                break;
            case 3:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//marzo
                $nombre='marzo';
                break;
            case 4:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//abril
                $nombre='abril';
                break;
            case 5:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//mayo
                $nombre='mayo';
                break;
            case 6:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//junio
                $nombre='junio';
                break;
            case 7:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//julio
                $nombre='julio';
                break;
            case 8:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//agosto
                $nombre='agosto';
                break;
            case 9:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//septiembre
                $nombre='septiembre';
                break;
            case 10:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//octubre
                $nombre='octubre';
                break;
            case 11:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//noviembre
                $nombre='noviembre';
                break;
            case 12:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre
                $nombre='diciembre';
                break;
        }

        $filas=ceil($cantidad_dias/7);//variable donde se guarda la cantidad del primer ciclo

        $cantidad_celdas=$filas*7;//numero de dias que se van  a imprimir
        $diferencia=$cantidad_celdas -$cantidad_dias;//variable que indica el fin del segundo ciclo


        //for($r=1;$r<2;$r++)//ciclo que guarda en una tabla los calendarios generados
        //{
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir las primeras 4 columnas
        {
                echo '<td>    '.$i.'   </td>';
                if($i % 7 == 0)//separar por filas
                {
                    $arreglo[$i-1]=$i;
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
        }

        for ($i=1;$i<=$diferencia;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir la quinta columna
        {
                echo '<td>**</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
        echo'</table>';
        //}

        $datos=array($nombre,$año);
        return $datos;
    }
?>
```

Asi se ve el calendario que llevo:
[image: Asi se ve el calendario que llevo]

Asi me gustaria que se viera, no importa si está centrada, pero si que se vea más de un mes por renglón
[image: Asi me gustaria que se viera, no importa si está centrada, pero si que se vea más de un mes por renglón]

Aquí esta definido los rangos del ciclo, también corregí los saltos de fecha al principio de mes y agregué la quinta columna cuando no empiezan en domingo

```
<?php

function generarMes($añoInicio,$mesInicio,$añoFin,$mesFin,$renglones)
{
    $añoInicio;//variable que identifica a partir de que año empieza el calendario
        $añoFin;
        $cantidad_dias = 0;//donde se almacena la cantidad de dias por mes
        $numero_mes = $mesInicio;//identifica el mes y van desde 1 hasta 12

        echo "numero de mes antes del switch: ".$numero_mes;

        switch($numero_mes)//devuelve la cantidad de dias de cada mes
        {
            case 1:
            echo"numero mes: ".$numero_mes;
            $cantidad_dias=31;//enero
                    $nombre='enero';
                    break;
            case 2:
            $cantidad_dias=28;//febrero
                    $nombre='febrero';
                    break;
            case 3:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//marzo
                    $nombre='marzo';
                    break;
            case 4:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//abril
                    $nombre='abril';
                    break;
            case 5:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//mayo
                    $nombre='mayo';
                    break;
            case 6:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//junio
                    $nombre='junio';
                    break;
            case 7:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//julio
                    $nombre='julio';
                    break;
            case 8:
                    $cantidadtidad_dias=31;//agosto
                    $nombre='agosto';
                    break;
            case 9:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//septiembre
                    $nombre='septiembre';
                    break;
            case 10:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//octubre
                    $nombre='octubre';
                    break;
            case 11:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//noviembre
                    $nombre='noviembre';
                    break;
            case 12:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre
                    $nombre='diciembre';
                break;
        }

        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $numero_mes, 1, $añoInicio);
        $fechaSalteada = date("w", $timestamp);
        $cantidad_dias+=$fechaSalteada;

        $filas=ceil($cantidad_dias/7);//variable donde se guarda la cantidad del primer ciclo
        $cantidad_celdas=$filas*7;//numero de dias que se van  a imprimir
        $diferencia=$cantidad_celdas -$cantidad_dias;//variable que indica el fin del segundo ciclo

        echo $nombre.',';
        echo $añoInicio." ";
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';

        for ($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir las primeras 4 columnas
        {
            if ($i==1)
            {
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>D</td> <td>L </td> <td>M </td> <td>M </td> <td>J </td> <td>V </td> <td>S</td>
                    </tr>";
        }

        if($i<=$fechaSalteada)
        {
                echo'<td></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            $numero_dia=$i-$fechaSalteada;
                echo '<td>    '.$numero_dia.'   </td>';
        }

        if($i % 7 == 0)//separar por filas
        {
                echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        }

        for ($i=1;$i<=$diferencia;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir la quinta columna
        {
        echo '<td></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo'</table>';

}
?>


<?php
$mesInicio=5;
$añoInicio=2017;
$renglones=3;
$mesFin=5;
$añoFin=2018;

generarMes($añoInicio,$mesInicio,$añoInicio,$mesInicio,$renglones);
generarMes($añoInicio+1,$mesInicio,$añoInicio,$mesInicio, $renglones);
?>
```

// Pero como lo planteaste @Kenny, no sé como hacer el ciclo en el cual haga aumente el año y recorra los meses para cubrir el intervalo.

```
function generarMes($numero_mes) 
{ 
    $mes = []; 
    $cantidad_dias=0;//donde se almacena la cantidad de dias por mes 
    switch($numero_mes)//devuelve la cantidad de dias de cada mes 
    { 
        case 1: 
            $cantidad_dias=31;//enero 
            $nombre='enero'; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
        $cantidad_dias=28;//febrero 
        $nombre='febrero'; 
        break; 
        case 3: $cantidad_dias=31;//marzo 
            $nombre='marzo'; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            $cantidad_dias=30;//abril 
            $nombre='abril'; 
            break; 
        case 5: $cantidad_dias=31;//mayo 
            $nombre='mayo'; 
            break; 
        case 6: 
            $cantidad_dias=30;//junio 
            $nombre='junio'; 
            break; 
        case 7: 
            $cantidad_dias=31;//julio 
            $nombre='julio'; 
            break; 
        case 8: 
            $cantidad_dias=31;//agosto 
            $nombre='agosto'; break; 
        case 9: 
            $cantidad_dias=30;//septiembre 
            $nombre='septiembre'; 
            break; 
        case 10: 
            $cantidad_dias=31;//octubre 
            $nombre='octubre'; 
            break; 
        case 11: 
            $cantidad_dias=30;//noviembre 
            $nombre='noviembre'; 
            break; case 12: 
            $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre 
            $nombre='diciembre'; 
            break; 

        case 12:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre
                    $nombre='diciembre';
                    break;
        }

        for($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)
        {   
            array_push($mes, "<td>".$i."</td>");
        }

        return $mes;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir una imagen con una representación gráfica de lo que quieres? Tal y como está ahora la pregunta, no se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres o qué es lo hace el código

Comment: Añadí la foto de como está mi calendario y el bosquejo de como se vería, lo hice con 2 "meses", me sale con html, pero con php no

Comment: ¿Cuando dices "en un solo renglon" te refieres a que las tablas que continene los dias de los meses aparezcan una a la par de la otra (en ves de por debajo) o te refieres a una sola linea de texto que tenga todos los dias de los 10 meses?

Comment: si, que el mes de enero, salga al lado de febrero separados como tablas, en una sola linea si me sale (mi primer error), pero no logro mostrar que las tablas tengan esa forma, ya que mi programa va a mostrar rangos de fechas y quiero imprimir los meses como calendarios, y para evitar los scrolls, por eso quiero imprimir hasta 10 meses en un solo renglón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo, así quedó mi función generar calendario y como resolví el problema de como mostrar varias columnas por renglón.

```
<?php

function generarMes($añoInicio,$mesInicio)
{
        $nombre='';
        $cantidad_dias = 0;//donde se almacena la cantidad de dias por mes
    $numro_mes = $mesInicio;//identifica el mes y van desde 1 hasta 12

    switch($numero_mes)//devuelve la cantidad de dias de cada mes
    {
            case 1:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//enero
                    $nombre='enero';
                break;
            case 2:
                if($añoInicio%4==0)
                        $cantidad_dias=29;//febrero
                    else
                        $cantidad_dias=28;//febrero
                    $nombre='febrero';
                    break;
            case 3:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//marzo
                    $nombre='marzo';
                    break;
            case 4:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//abril
                $nombre='abril';
                    break;      
            case 5:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//mayo
                    $nombre='mayo';
                    break;
            case 6:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//junio
                    $nombre='junio';
                    break;
            case 7:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//julio
                    $nombre='julio';
                    break;
            case 8:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//agosto
                    $nombre='agosto';
                    break;
            case 9:
                    $cantidad_dias=30;//septiembre
                    $nombre='septiembre';
                    break;
            case 10:
                $cantidad_dias=31;//octubre
                    $nombre='octubre';
                    break;
            case 11:
                $cantidad_dias=30;//noviembre
                    $nombre='noviembre';
                    break;
            case 12:
                    $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre
                    $nombre='diciembre';
                    break;
            }

    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $numero_mes, 1, $añoInicio);
    $fechaSalteada = date("w", $timestamp);
    $cantidad_dias+=$fechaSalteada;

    $filas=ceil($cantidad_dias/7);//variable donde se guarda la cantidad del primer ciclo
    $cantidad_celdas=$filas*7;//numero de dias que se van  a imprimir
    $diferencia=$cantidad_celdas -$cantidad_dias;//variable que indica el fin del segundo ciclo



    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<h3>'.$nombre.','.$añoInicio.'</h3>';
    for ($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir las primeras 4 columnas
    {
        if ($i==1)
        {
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>D</td> <td>L </td> <td>M </td> <td>M </td> <td>J </td> <td>V </td> <td>S</td>
                </tr>";
        }

        if($i<=$fechaSalteada)
        {
                echo'<td></td>';
        }
        else
        {
                $numero_dia=$i-$fechaSalteada;
                echo '<td>    '.$numero_dia.'   </td>';
        }

        if($i % 7 == 0)//separar por filas
        {
                echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }

    for ($i=1;$i<=$diferencia;$i++)//ciclo para imprimir la quinta columna
        {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo'</table>';
}
?>

<?php
        $mesInicio=(int)$_GET["mesInicio"];
        $mesFin=(int)$_GET["mesFin"];
        $añoInicio=(int)$_GET["anioInicio"];
        $añoFin=(int)$_GET["anioFin"];
        $renglones=(int)$_GET["renglon"];

        $i=1;//variable del ciclo
        $j=(int)$mesInicio;//control de meses y aumento de año
        $reinicioMes=$j;

        $k=0;//variable que aumenta los años
        $diferenciaMeses=(($añoFin - $añoInicio) * 12) + ($mesFin - $mesInicio);//variable que calcula la cantidad de meses que se van a imprimr
        $modulo=1;

        echo'<table>';

    for($i=1;$i<=$diferenciaMeses+1;$i++)
    {
        if($i%$renglones==0)//obtener fin de renglón
                $modulo+=$renglones;

        if($i==1 ||$i==$modulo)//inicio de renglón
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
    if($j>=12)
    {
        $j = 0;
            $k++;
            $reinicioMes = 1;
    }
            echo"<td>";
            generarMes($añoInicio+$k,$reinicioMes,$renglones);
            echo "</td>";
        $j++;
        $reinicioMes+=1;

    if($i%$renglones == 0 || $i==$diferenciaMeses+1)//fin de renglón
    {

            echo "</tr>";
    }


        if($i>=$diferenciaMeses)//final de tabla
        {
                echo'</table>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución para tu problema es generar los calendarios en un arreglo y despues imprimirlos en el orden que quieres. Entonces imagino que tu función `generarMes` es una función que llamas desde alguna otra parte de tu código, ¿cierto?. Bueno, imagina que tu función quedará así:

```
function generarMes($numero_mes)
{
    $mes = [];
    $cantidad_dias=0;//donde se almacena la cantidad de dias por mes
    switch($numero_mes)//devuelve la cantidad de dias de cada mes
    {
        case 1:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//enero
            $nombre='enero';
            break;
        case 2:
            $cantidad_dias=28;//febrero
            $nombre='febrero';
            break;
        case 3:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//marzo
            $nombre='marzo';
            break;
        case 4:
            $cantidad_dias=30;//abril
            $nombre='abril';
            break;
        case 5:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//mayo
            $nombre='mayo';
            break;
        case 6:
            $cantidad_dias=30;//junio
            $nombre='junio';
            break;
        case 7:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//julio
            $nombre='julio';
            break;
        case 8:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//agosto
            $nombre='agosto';
            break;
        case 9:
            $cantidad_dias=30;//septiembre
            $nombre='septiembre';
            break;
        case 10:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//octubre
            $nombre='octubre';
            break;
        case 11:
            $cantidad_dias=30;//noviembre
            $nombre='noviembre';
            break;
        case 12:
            $cantidad_dias=31;//diciembre
            $nombre='diciembre';
            break;
    }

    for($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)
    {   
        array_push($mes, "<td>".$i."</td>");
    }

    return $mes;
}
```

En este caso, es el mismo `switch` que ya tienes, y un ciclo `for` al final que en vez de separar por semanas, solamente incluye todos los dias listados en un arreglo. Al final, la funcion devuelve este arreglo que contiene todos los dias de tu mes, ya con la etiqueta `td` incluida, esto para que sea más facil imprimirlos después.

Ahora imagina que llamas a esa función unas 10 veces y guardas el resultado en otro arreglo, y despues usas otros ciclos para imprirmirlo como tu quieres. Algo como así:

```
<table> 
    <?php
    $arr_meses = [];

    for($i=0;$i < 10;$i++)
    {
        array_push($arr_meses, generarMes(4));
    }

    echo "<tr>";

    for($i=1;$i < 6;$i++)
    {
        for($x=0;$x < 10;$x++)
        {
            for($j=(7*$i)-7;$j < (7*$i);$j++)
            {
                if($j % 7 == 0)
                    echo "<td>|</td>";
                if($j < 30)
                    echo $arr_meses[$x][$j];
                else
                    echo "<td>*</td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    ?>
</table>
```

Lo explico paso por paso, porque mi solución plantea un caso con una matriz bidimensional con un recorrido mas o menos tridimensional y que la verdad se oye más complejo de lo que en realidad es.

1. Abrimos la etiqueta `table`
2. La variable `arr_mes` tendra en cada posición un arreglo con los dias de los meses que ha generado la función `generarMes`
3. Llamamos a la función `generarMes` cuantas veces sea necesario. En este caso yo lo hice 10 veces porque eso es lo que planteaste en tu pregunta y le puse la misma cantidad de dias (30) porque no se como haces para llamar a esa función. Pero puedes cambiar eso cuando quieras, y llamarla con los dias que necesites, que al fin de todo para eso es el `switch`
4. Abrimos la etiqueta `tr` que indica el comienzo de una fila, ya despues los ciclos se encargaran de abrirla una y otra vez.
5. El primer ciclo indica la cantidad de filas que imprimiremos, que en este caso son 5, ya que siempre hay 5 filas en cada mes. Va de 1 a 6 para ayudarnos un poquito en el tercer ciclo.
6. El segundo ciclo nos indica que debemos recorrer todos los "meses" que estan guardados en el arreglo `arr_meses`, sean 10, 8 o 5, eso ya depende de ti.
7. El tercer ciclo estará imprimiendo los primeros 7 dias, despues los segundos 7 dias y asi sucesivamente, es por eso que debemos relacionarlo con la fila en general que nos encontramos imprimiendo para saber de donde a donde imprimir.
8. Cuando sabemos que llegamos al final de la linea, por mes, imprimimos un "|" solo para delimitar un poco.
9. En caso de pasarnos de los dias (en este caso yo puse 30 porque se que tengo 30 en cada mes, pero podrias modificarlo para que sea el largo del arreglo que estas analizando ya que el largo es igual al numero de dias) imprimimos solo asteriscos.
10. Al final de cada fila general, imprimimos `</tr><tr>` para pasar a la siguiente fila general.

De esta forma, podras imprimir los meses que necesites en el mismo "renglón".

Comment: redefiní la función para que pueda acceder a los rangos del intervalo de fechas y de meses por renglón, pero no supe como aplicarlo a tu código, por eso subí las mejoras que tengo del anterior

Comment: Mira, lo mejor siempre es que puedas editar tu pregunta en vez de publicar una respuesta. Yo respondi a tu pregunta de como corregir la impresion de los calendarios, pero para los intervalos de fechas, aun cuando lo mencionaste, no fue parte de tu pregunta. Aun puedes editar tu pregunta y definirla bien para que podamos seguir ayudandote.